# Как экспортировать 2-х уровневый cxGrid в Exсel?

Tags: delphi, excel, devexpress

Мне нужно экспортировать 2-х уровневый девэкспресовсовский cxGrid в MSExcel. `ExportGridToExсel` экспортирует только 1-й уровень.